# Get observable, but wait for promise before activating

Tags: promise, angular, observable, rxjs

I need to wait for a promise to complete before activating an observable in Angular 2 with RxJS.

More specifically, I need to set up state using a third party library that returns promises, and insert some resulting information into my HTTP headers before making GET requests:

```
export class LiveDataService {

    private headersPromise;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.headersPromise = $.connection('/init').then((state) => setupHeaders(state));
    }

    activate(route: string) {
        return this.http.get('api/v1/' + route, { headers })
            .Merge(anotherStateBasedObservable);
    }

)
```

Except, although I need to return the observable immediately as shown, I also must wait for the promise to complete before calling the `http.get`.

I can think of a couple ways that require like 3-4 stages of translation, but I feel like there should be a fairly direct way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you really need an observable to be returned? I would do something like this:

```
// getState caches the state promise, so '/init' gets requested only once
// but is lazy loaded
var _statePromise = null;
function getState() {
  return _statePromise || (_statePromise = $.connection('/init'));
}

function routeChange(route) {
  return getState()
    .then(state => setupHeaders(state))
    .then(headers => this.http.get('api/v1/' + route, { headers }));
}
```

**EDIT**

You can map an observable with async functions using `flatMap` or [`flatMapLatest`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmaplatest.md):

```
// routeSource is an RxJS Observable
var contentSource = routeSource.flatMapLatest(routeChange);
```

**EDIT**

You can convert promises to observables and vica versa: [Bridging Promises](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/promises.md)

This might be what you need:

```
// getState caches the state promise, so '/init' gets requested
// only once, but is lazy loaded
var _statePromise = null;
function getState() {
  return _statePromise || (_statePromise = $.connection('/init'));
}
function Method(route) {
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(this.getState())
    .flatMap(state => setupHeaders(state)) // flatMap handles promises
    .flatMap(headers => this.http.get('api/v1/' + route, { headers }))
    .merge(anotherStateBasedObservable);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do need an observable. Otherwise I have a promise to an observable, and I have to unwrap twice in each caller. More importantly (which I know I did not mention), the purpose of the stateful information is to chain other observable information. Lastly, since observables appear to be the norm in angular 2, I don't think I want to start wrapping observables in promises.

Comment: @shannon You certainly shouldn't have to wrap observables in promises, as promises themselves are like lightweight, single-valued observables. I edited my code so it maps to an Observable (Most RxJS Observable composition functions accept promises too)

Comment: Could you please clarify how you are suggesting I could apply `flatMap`?

Comment: @shannon What does `http.get` return? Does it return a promise or an observable?

Comment: I agree with the `getState` suggestion. In my code I actually use a singleton / initialization, which I clarified above. I don't see in your code where you return an observable as you mentioned in your last comment.

Comment: `http.get` returns an observable in Angular 2

Comment: I feel slightly like the flatten operator obfuscates the intent, but that's nothing a comment can't clean up. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: This is working for me (although `flatMap` was renamed `mergeMap` in rxjs 5.0)

Comment: @shannon I totally agree with you that `flatMap` mantles the original intent. Somehow I feel like http.get should remain an ordinary promise-returning async function, otherwise es7 async-await syntax is useless

Comment: I'm thinking about reworking this with a custom observable. It would only be a couple additional lines of code, would be slightly clearer, and would allow me to handle unsubscribe (maybe via `publish().refcount()`) to tear down something I need to on router navigation events. I'm investigating right now whether `| async` in angular 2.0 beta wires up `dispose()`. If it does, I'll be very glad Observables have become first-class citizens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100323/discussion-between-shannon-and-hege-hegedus).